# Bootstrap navbar issue, extra space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my website http://webninjas.eu/.
The problem with my navbar is extra space when I press "Get started" button from the top of the page or any element from navbar when the website is in mobile phone resolution.

[Screen-shot of the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuNs0.jpg)

I know that the problem is comming from z-index but I don't know how to fix.
The difference between 768 < resolution:

```
element.style {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    width: 1035px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

and resolution < 768:

```
element.style {
    z-index: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
}
```

I have tried to give 768 < resolution parameters to .main-nav-outer but the the results are not even close to what I need.

Comment: you have to describe your problem as well as your expectation clearly so people could help you out!

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have given offset of 102

```
 $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 102
            }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
```

change this to 0

Comment: If I will put 0 this will stop the animation, I put 50 instead 102 and this solved the issue. You gave me the idea how to solve the problem, best answer. Thank you.

Comment: Did it, need to be approved :)